# Solving nonhomogenous differential equation using undetermined coefficients.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve:

$y'' - y = e^{-t}(2\sin t + 4\cos t)$

$y(0) = 1, y'(0) = 1$

What can I guess for the RHS of the differential equation?  I was thinking I could use the information listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients), but I'm having a hard time translating the question into something I can solve.  Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see on that page that it says if the function of $x$ (which, for you, means $t$) is $ke^{ax}\cos bx$ or $ke^{ax}\sin bx$ then the form for $y$ is $e^{ax}(K\cos bx+M\sin bx)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try finding a solution that looks like the rhs of the equation. For example 
$$
w(t) = A e^{-t} \cos(t)
$$
has as first and second derivatives
\begin{align}
w'(t) &= -A e^{-t} \cos(t) - A e^{-t}\sin(t),\\
w''(t) &= 2 A e^{-t} \sin(t),
\end{align}
hence
$$
w'' - w = 2 A e^{-t} \sin(t) - A e^{-t} \cos(t).
$$
This would imply that $A = 1$ and $A = -4$ at the same time, which cannot be. We need another function.

Now, what other function -besides $A e^{-t} \cos(t)$-, has derivatives with terms $e^{-t}\sin(t)$, $e^{-t}\cos(t)$?

Comment: Is it $Ae^{-t}\sin t$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Corrected. Thanks.

Comment: @user, why don't you try it, and see for yourself?

Comment: Ok!  Thanks for the help :)